# Can you extern a #define variable in another file?

Tags: c, global, extern

For example **abc.c** contains a variable

```
#define NAME "supreeth"
```

Can extern the variable `NAME` in **def.c**?

Comment: A define is a preprocessor directive. It is replaced inline when compiling the code. You will need to define it in a header (include) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `#define NAME "supreeth"` in abc.c, you can surely have a extern variable by same name in another file `def.c`, this is as far as the compiler is concerned.  If you are implying some kind of dependency between these two, that dependency/linkage will not happen.
Obviously it is confusing and a bad idea to do something like this.

Answer (score 23):

You can not use `extern` with macro. but if you want your macro seen by many C files

put your macro definition

```
#define NAME "supreeth"
```

in a header file like **def.h**

then include your **def.h** in your C code and then you can use your macro in your C file in all other C file if you include **def.h**

Comment: What's possible? There is no variable, and the concept of `extern` doesn't apply.

Comment: I did not mean using extern I ean he can define his macro in the header file then he can see it from his C files . may be I have to be more specific I will update my answer

Answer (score 16):

In your code `NAME` is not a variable. It's a pre-processor symbol, which means the text `NAME` will be replaced everywhere in the input with the string `"supreeth"`. This happens per-file, so it doesn't make sense to talk about it being "external".

If a particular C file is compiled without that `#define`, any use of `NAME` will remain as-is.