# Sharing #define in non header file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

To the best of my knowledge I thought you can only share a `#define` in header files or only in the source file it was declared in. [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275950/is-it-possible-to-use-define-from-other-cpp-file) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279975/can-you-extern-a-define-variable-in-another-file) like these seem to support my belief that defines can only be shared through header files.

In the FFmpeg libavutil v6.0 source code, [tx_priv.h](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/tx_priv.h) uses 3 defines `TX_FLOAT`, `TX_DOUBLE`, and `TX_INT32`. These 3 defines are declared in [tx_float.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/tx_float.c), [tx_double.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/tx_double.c), and [tx_int32.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/tx_int32.c) respectively. I'm wondering how can [tx_priv.h](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/tx_priv.h) access the defines declared in source files? Shouldn't the default `#else` always resolve?

This is mostly in the context of other compilers/build tools than the included make. I want to build FFmpeg but I'm trying to understand this issue.

I was expecting for the file `tx_priv.h` to never be able to check if the defines `TX_FLOAT`, `TX_DOUBLE`, and `TX_INT32` are actually ever defined.

Comment: `#include` directive is very simple - it reads the file and pastes entire content in place of this directive. If you copy and paste content of `tx_priv.h` into `tx_float.c`, can you see what happens?

Comment: As I can see in the repo, ```tx_priv.h``` is included juste after the ```#define TX_FLOAT``` directive, in this case you're sure that this particular inclusion of ```tx_priv.h``` will see ```TX_FLOAT```.
The other way around, ```tx_priv.h``` is included in many places where the various macro may or may not be defined. It seems a way to use different sections of ```tx_priv.h``` according to the context of inclusion.
So yes it's "working" but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do so (perhaps...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files are not compiled themselves, the code within is when they are included in source files that get compiled.

This way the code within a header *can* see any symbols that have been `#define`d before the header has been included, e.g. for `tx_int32.c` that might look as:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define TX_INT32 int32_t

#include "tx_priv.h"
```

On compiling `tx_int32.c` the pre-processor will replace the `#include` directive with the entire contents of the file to be included (and most likely continue pre-processing these right on the fly, but that's not the point here…), so after the inclusions the source file might look like:

```
typedef int int32_t;
// all the other typedefs of stdint.h

#define TX_INT32 int32_t

#ifdef TX_INT32
// whatever...
#endif
```

Side note: The name of the header sounds like being intended to *never* be (directly?) included by the user...

Comment: I see, so they are including the header file into the different tx_ types, like templated creation.